# How to read query parameters in Revel using the 'routes' file?

Tags: go, url, query-string, revel

I am new to Revel and golang. I need help as to how can I access query paramters in Revel and configure it in routes.

Example: `localhost:9000/company?name=ABC`.

I am sending above get request to fetch the company by name from database. I don't know how can I configure it in the `routes` file.

My action has

```
func (c APP) ShowByName(name string){..}
```

This is how I have set the routes:

```
GET /company?name:name      APP.ShowByName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this.

In action I placed the below code :

```
c.Params.Query=c.Request.URL.Query()
var limit int
c.Params.Bind(&limit,"limit")
```

and it work for the below URL:

```
localhost:9000?limit=21
```

Here is the complete code for that
[revel read query parameter](https://github.com/rishirajdev/revel-queryParameters.git)

Answer (score 0):

According to revel documentation, all request parameters are collected into the single Params object which includes:

```
The URL /:path parameters
The URL ?query parameters
Submitted Form values
File multipart uploads
```

Extracted parameters are available via Action method [`parameters`](https://revel.github.io/manual/parameters.html).

```
type Params struct {
    url.Values
    Files map[string][]*multipart.FileHeader
}
```

Checking the Params struct we can observe that it use [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values)

According to above information the query param url route can be set as:

```
GET    /company/:name?name            APP.ShowByName
```

And the controller action:

```
func (c APP) ShowByName(name string) revel.Result {
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi @simo-endre thanks for your answer.So if we pass the url : localhost:9000/company?name=ABC so the route in your answer will handle this?

Answer (score 0):

URL query parameters are automatically passed to controllers.

In your `routes` file, just specify the URL path (ignoring the query string).
For the example `localhost:9000/company?name=ABC` given in the question, you would just have:

```
(routes file)

GET /company      SomeController.ShowByName
```

Then within the controller, just add function parameters. Revel will bind these to the appropriate query string values:

```
func (c SomeController) ShowByName(name string) revel.Result {
  if name == "" {
    // handle missing or empty
  }
  // ...
}
```